# "The feature you are trying to access..." from MSI with simple install package

Tags: visual-studio, installation, windows-installer

I created a MSI package with visual studio. It works fine for 80% of the users (some have errors with privileges and the like), but for two users the installation fails with the error message:

> The feature you are trying to use is on a network resource that is unavailable

Which I find very odd because all the MSI does is set some registry values and put an OCX control into the system. Nothing with any network devices or anything else.

It also refers to a `install[1].msi` (when the actual MSI is called `install.msi`) which it supposedly can't find, which is obvious, because such a file never existed and is neither required for the installation nor even referenced in it in any way.

The package tries to locate this non-existent other package under `C:\Documents and Settings\XYZ\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5\M84S9GA4\`, even though I started the MSI out of the local drive `D:`.

How can I resolve this / get closer the underlying cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A verbose log file should show you the exact error causing the issue. If it doesn't happen consistently, you'll probably be best served turning on [the logging policy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369776%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get a log file all the time and when it repros, grab the log file really quick.

Alternatively, if you have a repro situation you can get a log file immediately by doing:

```
msiexec /i path\to\your.msi /l*v install.txt
```

As for the root cause, the fact that that the name is `install[1].msi` makes it sound like the MSI was downloaded using a web browser and launched out of the browser cache. The Windows Installer is very particular about the name of the MSI, you can read about that in an [old blog entry of mine](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robmen/archive/2004/12/08/278746.aspx). The end result is that shipping a 'naked' MSI on the internet is never a good idea. Maybe you're seeing these errors when shipping a newer MSI? If so, that would make a lot of sense.

A verbose log file will show you for sure.

Comment: Heh, edit came in after my answer. I now **really** believe that the MSI was downloaded and launched out of the browser cache. :)

Comment: How can I create a verbose log file for that matter?

Comment: PS@comment: I downloaded the file to a local drive, `D:` and started it from there - the same error ocurred. I then even tried to use the `Browse` button of the error to navigate to that same MSI and try againg with that, but no changes...

Comment: I originally suggested setting logging policy to get the log file, and I enhanced the answer on how to get log file directly when you have a repro machine.

Comment: The error message helped very much - apparently, D: isn't D: at all - it was a mapped network drive which caused the error. Running it from C: solved it and it could be installed.